# Stop Bluetooth Auto Sync Contacts to Pioneer Avic Z140

Tags: sync, bluetooth

Am running Cm7.1.  I have about 2,000 contacts. My Nexus One and Pioneer headunit insist on exchanging all 2,000 contacts if my Android Contacts "Display Options" are set to "My Contacts." Problem is that this really makes Voice Recognition unusable (too many contacts to parse).

To get around this, I created a "Car" label in Gmail for the 21 contacts I want. If I change the "Display Options" to just "Car," only the 21 contacts are synced and VR works great. Problem is that when not in the car, I would like "My Contacts" to visible on my phone.

I would like to sync only the "Car" label, or only sync manually. I can't figure out a way to control this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filtered contacts list solves this problem, but unfortunately if you are like me you are constantly needing to look at the larger list of contacts and you will not remember to turn the filter back on afterwards. So when you get back into the car, it will start sending the whole list again. I just found a workaround.

There are a ton of alternative contact apps in the marketplace that will sync to your gmail contacts. I installed GO Contacts EX https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbapps.contactpro&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5qYmFwcHMuY29udGFjdHBybyJd

It appears that the bluetooth address book is only controlled by the stock contacts app, which I've left filtered. I banished the stock app from my home screen/launcher. All good now.